# Absolute path for almond when using require.js optimize

Tags: requirejs, almond

I'm trying to get my code to optimize to a single file using what is apparently a non-standard setup and I'm struggling to understand what all the different paths mean.

Imagine I'm making a variant of `r` [the requirejs command-line tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics) that includes almond. So I want to be able to wrap with almond using the almond included with my tool.

My directory structure

```
someAppFolder
|
+--main.js
```

In an related folder

```
myRPlusAlmondBuilder
|
+--myRPlusAlmonBuilder.js
|
+--node_modules
   |
   +--almond
   |  |
   |  +--almond.js
   |
   +--requirejs
      |
      ...
```

So, I want `myRPlusAlmondBuilder` to be able to build a single JS bundle from `main.js` like this

```
cd myRPlusAlmondBuilder
node myRPlusAlmondBuilder.js someAppFolder/main.js
```

Here's a simple myRPlusAlmondBuilder.js

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
var path = require('path');

var filename = process.argv[2];                
var dirname = path.dirname(filename);          
var barename = path.basename(filename, ".js"); 

var config = {
  baseUrl: dirname,
  name: "node_modules/almond/almond",
  include: barename,
  insertRequire: [barename],
  out:     "out.js",
  wrap:    true,
};

// show the values 
console.log(JSON.stringify(config, undefined, "  "));

requirejs.optimize(config, function() {
  console.log("result is in:", config.out);
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

calling it like this

```
cd myRPlusAlmondBuilder.js
node myRPlusAlmondBuilder.js /Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/someAppFolder/main.js
```

but I get

```
{
  "baseUrl": "/Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/someAppFolder",
  "name": "node_modules/almond/almond",
  "include": "main",
  "insertRequire": [
    "main"
  ],
  "out": "out.js",
  "wrap": true
}
{ [Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: /Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/someAppFolder/node_modules/almond/almond.js for module named: node_modules/almond/almond. Path is relative to: /Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/myRPlusAlmondBuilder
```

Trying these other values for `name` all fail

```
// dot in front 
name: "./node_modules/almond/almond",

// .js on end
name: "node_modules/almond/almond.js",

// .dot in front and .js on end
name: "./node_modules/almond/almond.js",

// absolute path to almond.js with .js
name: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/almond/almond.js"),

// absolute path to almond.js without .js
name: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/almond/almond"),
```

The ones with ".js" get

```
[Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/someAppFolder/node_modules/almond/almond.js'
at Error (native)
]
```

The ones with the full path get

```
[Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/someAppFolder//Users/gregg/temp/delme-requirejs/myRPlusAlmondBuilder/node_modules/almond/almond.js'
at Error (native)
]
```

Using a relative path from main.js to almond works

```
name: path.relative(dirname, path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/almond/almond.js")),
```

But that won't work in windows if the tool in in `C:/somefolder/myRPlusAlmond` and the file in in `D:/someAppFolder/main.js`

Is there any way to use absolute paths for almond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way which is to add a path for almond

```
var config = {
  baseUrl: dirname,
  name: "__dontclash_almond__/almond",
  include: barename,
  insertRequire: [barename],
  out:     "out.js",
  wrap:    true,
  paths: {
    __dontclash_almond__: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/almond"),
  }.
};
```

Seems kind of hacky because I have to hope I don't clash with a user chosen name. Of course it's unlikely to clash